# How to find if an input starts with a certain string from a set

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```py
my_items = {'apple','banana','orange'}
x = input("Enter a string : ")
```

I need to check whether the input starts with any one of the strings in the set and execute some code if it is true. For example, if the input is "apple is tasty", then it should execute some code, else just pass. How do I do that?

Comment: Combine `any()` and `startswith()`. Or convert the items to a regular expression.

Comment: What if the input is "apples are tasty"? Match or not?

Comment: If you are going to vote to close for `Needs more focus` do the OP a favor - they're a newbie - and *comment your objections*.  To me, and apparently others too, this question is perfectly clear.  And esp, esp, if you also somehow found it useful to DV for that reason.

Comment: @JLPeyret Do those others to who it is perfectly clear include the answer authors, whose answers do different things? :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy 2 answers recognizably do what I thought I'd do.  Not sure where third one fits though.  As to *your* query, I'd say it is fairly unambiguously answered by the *title* of the question - "... starts with...".  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
my_items = {'apple','banana','orange'}
x = input("Enter a string : ")
output = any(x.startswith(i) for i in my_items)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
Enter a string : apple is tasty
True
```

If you want it to be true regarless of case you can use:

```
my_items = {'apple','banana','orange'}
x = input("Enter a string : ")
output = any(x.lower().startswith(i.lower()) for i in my_items)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split `x` with `' '` (space), so that you can obtain the item at index `[0]` which is the first word in the string. Then check if it exists in `my_items`:

```
splitVar = x.split(' ')
if splitVar[0] in my_items:
    #your code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use if-else

```py
my_items = {'apple','banana','orange'}
x = input("Enter a string : ")
for i in my_items:
    if x.startswith(i):
        #Write Your Code
        break
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: You should add `break` within the `if` so the loop doesn't run more than it has to...

Comment: Also, `else: pass` is not doing anything, it can be deleted too.